# SolrNet SpatialSearch for 2D/3D Objects

Tags: c#, search, solr, solrnet

I have been working on a trying to get SOLR's SpatialSearch adapters to work on searching for two dimensional and three dimensional objects. I tried to use solr.LatLonType but I have not been able to successfully add any data to the field that use that type. Then I figure there might be more information on solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType but I found even less help on using that type.
Here is what I have gotten so far:

```
// SOLR schema.xml
<field name="sheet" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="sheet_0_edge" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="sheet_1_edge" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />

// SolrNet Document
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using SolrNet.Attributes;

public class SheetIndexDocument
{
    public class SheetDocument
    {
        //Return identifiers
        [SolrField("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [SolrField("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [SolrField("sheet_0_edge")]
        public decimal? Width { get; set; }
        [SolrField("sheet_1_edge")]
        public decimal? Length { get; set; }
    }
}

// SolrNet WebService Index
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using ApplicationModel.Context;

public class SheetIndex : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string sCommand = context.Request.Params["Command"];
        if (sCommand == "Index")
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            this.IndexSheets(context);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void IndexSheets(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Connects the SOLR schema to our SOLR Doc in the App_Code section.
        SolrNet.ISolrOperations<SheetIndexDocument.SheetDocument> solr = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SolrNet.ISolrOperations<SheetIndexDocument.SheetDocument>>();
        SheetIndexDocument.SheetDocument oDoc = new SheetIndexDocument.SheetDocument();

        string sQuery = @"
            SELECT Id, Name, Width, Length 
            FROM [Sheet]
            ";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
                SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, cn);
                oCmd.CommandTimeout = 240;
                oCmd.Transaction = tr;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(reader);
                }
                oCmd.Transaction.Dispose();
                oCmd.Connection.Close();

                context.Response.Write("Number of Sheets to index: " + dt.Rows.Count + "\r");
                context.Response.Write("Indexing... \r\n");

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    //Sheet identifiers
                    int id = ToFieldValueOrNull<int>(row, "Id");
                    oDoc.Id = id.ToString();
                    oDoc.Name = ToFieldValueOrNull<string>(row, "Caption");

                    context.Response.Write("Added Item: " + oDoc.Name);
                    decimal? dWidth = 0.0m;
                    if (ToFieldValueOrNull<decimal?>(row, "Width").HasValue) dWidth = ToFieldValueOrNull<decimal?>(row, "Width");
                    context.Response.Write(" Loc(" + oDoc.Width);
                    decimal? dLength = 0.0m;
                    if (ToFieldValueOrNull<decimal?>(row, "Length").HasValue) dLength = ToFieldValueOrNull<decimal?>(row, "Length");
                    context.Response.Write("," + oDoc.Length + ")\r");

                    oDoc.Width = dWidth;
                    oDoc.Longitude = dLength;

                    solr.Add(oDoc);
                    context.Response.Flush();
                }
                context.Response.Write("Done\r\n");
                context.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            solr.Commit();
            context.Response.Write("Committed");
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
    }

    public T ToFieldValueOrNull<T>(DataRow row, string columnName)
    {
        if (row[columnName] == DBNull.Value) return default(T);
        T val = row.Field<T>(columnName);
        return val;
    }

    public List<string> ToFieldValuesOrNull(DataRow row, string columnName)
    {
        object val = row[columnName];
        if (row[columnName] == null) return null;
        return new List<string>(
            val.ToString().Split(new string[] { "|", ";", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        );
    }
}
```

Any direction on how to handle LatLonType or SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Using this FieldType:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_edge"/>
```

Comment: Are you using `location` as a `LatLonType` in your schema above?

Comment: Using this:    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_edge"/>

Comment: But there are no references to the field `sheet` or any other location in your document when indexing?

Comment: @fiskfisk I tried to reference it as a PointF but it would not take that as a valid type for "Location" or "LatLonType". Would be great if I knew what data type was needed for "LatLonType". Kinda coming up short on examples for SolrNet.

Comment: There's a Location type defined: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Location.cs - I'm guessing that's supposed to be used, although I'm not familiar with the internals of SolrNet. A Location field is just a String when indexing, so not sure if it would work just saying it's string and sending lat,lon as the value.

Comment: Thanks @fiskfisk, for the tip! You happen to know where the SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType type is in SolrNet? Was looking into using it for 3D searches, and once again come up kinda empty.

Comment: I think you'll have to fall back to PointType to query in more than two dimensions.